# GitLab pipeline failing as the test case is failing to execute due to TimeoutException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, maven-surefire-plugin

I am a software tester and I'm trying to deploy our project to build server. I have created automated testcases for our inhouse application. My manager asked me to create a GitLab CI/CD pipeline and then he'll use something from it to run the testcases on TeamCity. Please pardon me, if I don't make any sense while giving details as most of the process of this DevOps is confusing for me.

I have created a yaml config file. And when I'm running the pipeline, the build job is running successfully but the test job is failing. I'm not able to understand why is it failing. Because when I'm running the same testcase locally, they are executing successfully. I'm attaching the error log of the test job. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong and how do I resolve this.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)
  on windows git runner 1Royjy7z, system ID: s_e502a8fc0dbd
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on PNQ-I7-Z8850-04...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/1Royjy7z/0/code-monkeys/MooreNET/moorenet.warehouse.selenium/.git/
Checking out d3ba10ad as detached HEAD (ref is Selenium_testcases)...
Removing .m2/
git-lfs/3.0.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.17.2)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:14
Version:      16.2.0
Git revision: 782e15da
Git branch:   16-2-stable
GO version:   go1.20.5
Built:        2023-07-21T22:53:19+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Checking cache for default-non_protected...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=19740 revision=782e15da version=16.2.0
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ echo "Maven test started"
Maven test started
$ cd GRID
$ mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------------< GRID:GRID >------------------------------
[INFO] Building GRID 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M7/maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M7.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M7/maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M7.pom (7.2 kB at 5.1 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/3.0.0-M7/surefire-3.0.0-M7.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/3.0.0-M7/surefire-3.0.0-M7.pom (22 kB at 72 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M7/maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M7.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M7/maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M7.jar (44 kB at 95 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-extension-incubator/1.26.0-alpha/opentelemetry-extension-incubator-1.26.0-alpha.jar
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-extension-incubator/1.26.0-alpha/opentelemetry-extension-incubator-1.26.0-alpha.jar (7.2 kB at 24 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ GRID ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\1Royjy7z\0\code-monkeys\MooreNET\moorenet.warehouse.selenium\GRID\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ GRID ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ GRID ---
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GRID ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 41 source files to C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\1Royjy7z\0\code-monkeys\MooreNET\moorenet.warehouse.selenium\GRID\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ GRID ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Aug 18, 2023 4:38:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 116, so returning the closest version found: 115
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 144.492 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] testCases.ClickReloadOrgBtn.clickReloadBtn  Time elapsed: 120.354 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //div[@id='OrgTree_header-title-textEl']' (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:230)
    at pageObjects.HomePage.orgPanelVisibility(HomePage.java:44)
    at pageObjects.HomePage.expandPrefPanel(HomePage.java:69)
    at testCases.ClickReloadOrgBtn.clickReloadBtn(ClickReloadOrgBtn.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$$Lambda$92/25204999.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='OrgTree_header-title-textEl']"}
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.97)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_41'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [1f334e5f75af06ea37afe97591ceaf84, findElement {using=xpath, value=//div[@id='OrgTree_header-title-textEl']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 116.0.5845.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 116.0.5845.96 (1a3918166880..., userDataDir: C:\WINDOWS\SystemTemp\scope...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52358}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:52358/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 116.0.5845.97, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 1f334e5f75af06ea37afe97591ceaf84
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor17.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:349)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:304)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:287)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:205)
    ... 36 more
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   ClickReloadOrgBtn.clickReloadBtn:15 � Timeout Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //div[@id='OrgTree_header-title-textEl']' (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-18T16:40:52+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) on project GRID: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\1Royjy7z\0\code-monkeys\MooreNET\moorenet.warehouse.selenium\GRID\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Version:      16.2.0
Git revision: 782e15da
Git branch:   16-2-stable
GO version:   go1.20.5
Built:        2023-07-21T22:53:19+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=10496 revision=782e15da version=16.2.0
WARNING: target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\1Royjy7z\0\code-monkeys\MooreNET\moorenet.warehouse.selenium) 
WARNING: target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\1Royjy7z\0\code-monkeys\MooreNET\moorenet.warehouse.selenium) 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

This is my yaml file:

```
image: maven:latest  # Use a Maven image with Java pre-installed

stages: # Define the stages of the CI/CD pipeline
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/

# Define the job that will build and run the Selenium tests
build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd GRID  # Change directory to the project root
    - echo "Maven compile started"
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

test_job:
  stage: test
    # Use a Maven image with Java pre-installed
  # Specify the script to be executed as part of the job
  script:
    - echo "Maven test started"
    - cd GRID  # Change directory to the project root
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test  # Run the Maven test command
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
        - target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  environment: staging
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application"
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"
```

Comment: The issue from the error stack looks like it is do to with selenium not able to find the desired element. Nothing to do with the yaml file. You need to share the relevant HTML of the element and the selenium code.

Comment: You could add selenium screen video recording to your tests when tests fail, so that it eases your debugging experience. As mentioned, the test fails because the test cannot proceed as it waits for the desired element be loaded in the HomePage.

Comment: @Shawn When I'm running the same test cases locally, it is executing successfully. But I can't seem to find the issue why it's failing when run from the GitLab CI/CD pipeline. How do I find that?

Comment: @PhoenixAshes If I add selenium screen video recording to the tests, where will I get to see the video if I run the test cases from the pipeline?

Comment: @kunalkaklij your job should save them as artifacts in the CI, you can then see them directly on GitLab, download them, etc.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html